# Navigating to a new page in react not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, backend

When I try to add details to the signup page, the data is sent to MongoDB but the page is not navigating to the next one.

After adding the email and password to signup, the page should navigate to the onboarding page after submitting but it's not

This is the code snippet:

```
       const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/${isSignUp ? 'signup' :  'login'}`, { email, password })
        
       const success = response.status === 201

       if (success && isSignUp) navigate ('/onboarding')
       if (success && !isSignUp) navigate ('/dashboard')
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share where you got navigate() from? Are you using an external package to handle navigation?

Comment: Can you share the full component? Do you import { navigate } from 'react-router-dom';?

Comment: are you sure `success` is true? If not, this code as it stands will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `useNavigate` hook from the `react-router-dom` package and use it to `navigate` to the desired page:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Signup() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/${isSignUp ? 'signup' :  'login'}`, { email, password });
      const success = response.status === 201;

      if (success && isSignUp) navigate('/onboarding');
      if (success && !isSignUp) navigate('/dashboard');
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">{isSignUp ? 'Sign up' : 'Log in'}</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```